# Simulate internet routers, dns in a lab?

Tags: router, local-area-network

I need to test my software runs across the internet, i.e. two machines can talk to each other via host addresses and name resolution with routers and port-forwarding in between. What's the best way to do this? I can use any OS and set up on VMs.

Machine A
|
Router
|
Modem/Internet/WAN?
|
DNS Server
|
Modem/Internet/WAN?
|
Router
|
Machine B

Basically I need to simulate a machine having an internal IP address hidden to the other machine and the machine only accessible via another IP address (the router) with port forwarding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use WANem, a linux distro especially made to emulate internet.

- Official site : http://wanem.sourceforge.net/
- Article on PacketLife.net :
  http://packetlife.net/blog/2011/jan/12/emulating-wans-wanem/

Answer (score 0):

I've also managed to do this using two installations of VirtualBox, here's my notes:

- Have two machines, each will simulate a LAN
- Your router and physical LAN (192.168.1.x network) will simulate the WAN
- Setup VirtualBox on each machine, run guest on each
- Configure NAT on both Guests to not use default but specific LAN addressing:

  - *VBoxManage modifyvm "MachineA" --natnet1 "172.23.24/24**

    - This makes the NAT Guest network 172.23.24.x
    - Internal IP of host is 172.23.24.2
    - Guest is 172.23.24.15
    - External IP (WAN IP) is 192.168.1.x
- Configure NAT to alias as proxy, so WAN IP is passed through

  - *VBoxManage modifyvm "MachineA" --nataliasmode1 proxyonly*
- Set up hostnames on the router that map to the WAN address of each virtual box host, use these names as the connect addresses

*Quote from the User Manual:

> 9.10 Fine-tuning the VirtualBox NAT engine
>   9.10.1 Configuring the address of a NAT network interface In NAT mode,
>   the guest network interface is assigned to the IPv4 range 10.0.x.0/24
>   by default where x corresponds to the instance of the NAT interface
>   +2. So x is 2 when there is only one 145 9 Advanced topics NAT
>   instance active. In that case the guest is assigned to the address
>   10.0.2.15, the gateway is set to 10.0.2.2 and the name server can be
>   found at 10.0.2.3. If, for any reason, the NAT network needs to be
>   changed, this can be achieved with the following command: VBoxManage
>   modifyvm "VM name" --natnet1 "192.168/16"  This command would reserve
>   the network addresses from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.254.254 for the
>   first NAT network instance of “VM name”. The guest IP would be
>   assigned to
>   192.168.0.15 and the default gateway could be found at 192.168.0.2.